# Compare two collection in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

How can i compare two collections in backbone?

I have two collection 1C contains `1,2,3` while 2C contains `2,4,5` What i want to do is to remove `2` from 2C because 1C already has a value of 2 after that normally render the collection.

I tried this

```
this.1C.each(function(model1){
  this.2C.each(function(model2){
     if(model1 === model2){
        2C.remove(model2);
     }
  });
});
```

But it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that model1 and model2 are never the same instance of a model and therefore never match. Have you tried comparing model ID's or similar? eg. model1.id == model2.id

maybe add some debugging so you can see what's happening..

```
this.1C.each(function(model1){
  console.log('m1:'+model1.categoryCode);
  this.2C.each(function(model2){
     console.log('  m2:'+model2.categoryCode);
     if(model1.categoryCode == model2.categoryCode){
        console.log('removing m2:'+model2.categoryCode);
        2C.remove(model2);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you might be right. yes they are not identically the same. but they have the same categoryCode field. will those answer not work provided the situation?

Comment: you would need to specify that you want to compare on the categoryCode, so `model1.categoryCode == model2.categoryCode` should do it.

Comment: scratch my old comment. lol. i made it but doubles up the collection. meaning if the original collection is [1,2,3] it would render [3,3,3]

Comment: Thank you your answer led me to a solution which i already have just neglected some minor details.

Answer (score 5):

You have something called the Difference operator http://underscorejs.org/#difference. Which you can use like below

`var x = _.difference([1,2,3,4],[1,2]);
console.log(x); //gives [3,4]`

In your case you probably should do this

```
var reducedCollection = _.difference(this.1C.toJSON(),this.2C.toJSON());
```

which now will provide expected result

Comment: been trying this one but doesn't work for me. _.difference(this.1C, this.2C); not working

Comment: @Dreyfus15 I am sure `this.1C` does not give array does it? the above method has to be employed before you create collections. Store the data somewhere and then reuse that.

Comment: yes. i know that. so what i did is _.difference(1C.toArray(), 2C.toArray()) but nothing changed

Comment: Thank you your answer led me to a solution which i already have just neglected some minor details.

Answer (score 1):

The [proxied Underscore methods](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) can help you here. Try:

```
2C.without(1C.models);
```

`without` and the other proxied methods return arrays, so you’d have to wrap the result in another `Backbone.Collection`.

Comment: what do you mean by have to wrap the result in another Backbone.Collection.??

Comment: Thank you your answer led me to a solution which i already have just neglected some minor details.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library for event based collection comparison. Basically, I think you could achieve the results you are looking for with this library like so (haven't tested this specific case):

```
cocomp = new Backbone.CoComp({
  comparator: function(obj) {
    obj["1C"] === obj["2C"]
  }
});

// Listen for "cocomp:in:1C" on the 2C collection. This will be
// triggered if there is a match based on the comparator above.
2C.on("cocomp:in:1C", function(value) {
  2C.remove(value);
});

cocomp.set("1C", 1C)
cocomp.set("2C", 2C)
```

The GitHub repo is here: https://github.com/davidbiehl/backbone.cocomp

Let me know if this helps! The added benefit of this library is that if 1C or 2C ever changes (add, remove or reset), the event will be triggered if there is a match, effectively keeping 1C and 2C in sync.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
2C.remove(1C.models);
```

(if the model id is the basis of comparison check)

Answer (score 0):

The function updateCollection in this code https://github.com/3-16/Backbone-poller/blob/master/pusher.js works great to compare two collections for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = [];

arrNewCollection.forEach(function(item){ //get new collection
         if (!_.findWhere(arrOldCollection, {id: item.id})) { // find in old collection our property
                checked.push(item.id); // if in old collection can not find property then add this property in array
         }
    });
```